# How to calculate the expectation value (example)

Tags: probability, expectation

A transmitter is sending data packets. But some of these packets can get lost on the way. $N_r$ is the average number of transmission attempts including the successful one. The probability for j transmission attempts is:

$P(j) = PER^{j-1} (1-PER)$ with PER = packet error rate, so a probability

The expectation value of $N_r$ is: $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j\ PER^{j-1} (1-PER) = \frac{1}{1-PER}$

Well, I really don't understand how to come up with the right side of the last equation.

Comment: Put these 2 facts together: $\sum_{j\ge0}x^j = 1/(1-x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx} x^j = jx^{j-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $|x|<1$, the geometric series gives $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^{j}=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Hence, $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x^{j}=\frac{1}{1-x}-1=\frac{x}{1-x}$. We can differentiate this series term-by-term to obtain

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}jx^{j-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}.
$$

Hence, 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}jx^{j-1}(1-x)=\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$

Now, take $x=PER$ in your example.

Comment: very good explanation, thx so much!

Comment: You're welcome.